# Is there always a faceoff winner in ice hockey?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey

When the faceoff stat is collected in the NHL, can there be a draw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always possible to define a faceoff winner, because the definition of a faceoff win is simply whichever team first has possession of the puck (a brief possession is sufficient, anything longer than a deflection).  That must happen following a faceoff, so you can always declare a winner.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a source for this - nobody explains the stat officially.

Comment: As a edge case, what would happen if there was a faceoff with (say) 0.1s left and the puck went off down the ice without anyone touching it?

Comment: @PhilipKendall My feeling is that it would still be awarded as a win to the team whose side it went to - but like I said, I can't find any evidence of an official rule.  It may simply be up to the official scorer for the game (and hockey is like basketball - the official scorer tends to have a huge home team bias...)